# Qt 5.6 alpha QtWebEngine. How work with QWebEngineUrlRequestJob?

Tags: c++, qt, qwebkit, qt5.6

I have inherited from QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler. 
Redefined method requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *request)

After I try to call QWebEngineUrlRequestJob::reply

for example

```
void CustomUrlSchemeHandler::requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *request)
{
    qDebug() << "CustomUrlSchemeHandler::requestStarted -->>> " << request->requestUrl();

    QMimeDatabase HelpViewer;
    QMimeType mt = HelpViewer.mimeTypeForUrl(request->requestUrl());
    const QString mimeType = mt.name();
    QByteArray arr = QString::fromStdString("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>").toUtf8();
    QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer(&arr, this);
    buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    request->reply(mimeType.toLatin1(), buffer);

    return;
}
```

But the program crashes.
see log:

```
    [1126/113403:FATAL:weak_ptr.cc(26)] Check failed: sequence_checker_.CalledOnValidSequencedThread(). WeakPtrs must be checked on the same sequenced thread.
Backtrace:
    base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace [0x11A78691+33] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\debug\stack_trace_win.cc:205)
    logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage [0x119CB2AF+63] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\logging.cc:544)
    base::internal::WeakReference::Flag::IsValid [0x119FB75A+234] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\memory\weak_ptr.cc:28)
    base::internal::WeakReference::is_valid [0x119FB7B2+50] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\memory\weak_ptr.cc:43)
    base::WeakPtr<base::ObserverListBase<content::ServiceWorkerContextObserver> >::get [0x109EF57F+31] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\memory\weak_ptr.h:204)
    base::internal::InvokeHelper<1,void,base::internal::RunnableAdapter<void (__thiscall content::DownloadResourceHandler::*)(void)>,base::internal::TypeList<base::WeakPtr<content::DownloadResourceHandler> const &> >::MakeItSo [0x107B8ADB+11] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\bind_internal.h:300)
    base::internal::Invoker<base::IndexSequence<0>,base::internal::BindState<base::internal::RunnableAdapter<void (__thiscall content::DownloadResourceHandler::*)(void)>,void __cdecl(content::DownloadResourceHandler *),base::internal::TypeList<base::WeakPtr<c [0x107BAD0A+58] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\bind_internal.h:346)
    base::Callback<net::URLRequestContext * __cdecl(void)>::Run [0x1096CACF+47] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\callback.h:396)
    base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask [0x11A9580D+541] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\debug\task_annotator.cc:64)
    base::MessageLoop::RunTask [0x119DAAF8+456] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\message_loop\message_loop.cc:475)
    base::MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask [0x119D9204+52] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\message_loop\message_loop.cc:485)
    base::MessageLoop::DoWork [0x119D974D+221] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\message_loop\message_loop.cc:594)
    base::MessagePumpForIO::DoRunLoop [0x11A980A2+50] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\message_loop\message_pump_win.cc:524)
    base::MessagePumpWin::RunWithDispatcher [0x11A99B42+130] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\message_loop\message_pump_win.cc:51)
    base::MessagePumpWin::Run [0x11A99AAC+28] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\message_loop\message_pump_win.cc:58)
    base::MessageLoop::RunHandler [0x119DA907+247] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\message_loop\message_loop.cc:438)
    base::RunLoop::Run [0x11A0A2E6+70] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\run_loop.cc:56)
    base::MessageLoop::Run [0x119DA7BD+237] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\message_loop\message_loop.cc:288)
    base::Thread::Run [0x11A20AF6+22] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\threading\thread.cc:199)
    content::BrowserThreadImpl::IOThreadRun [0x10603B74+52] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\content\browser\browser_thread_impl.cc:212)
    content::BrowserThreadImpl::Run [0x1060498B+235] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\content\browser\browser_thread_impl.cc:246)
    base::Thread::ThreadMain [0x11A215F9+745] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\threading\thread.cc:248)
    base::`anonymous namespace'::ThreadFunc [0x11A283B6+262] (e:\lib\qt\qt_git\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\base\threading\platform_thread_win.cc:84)
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75D57C04+36]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77E4AD1F+143]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77E4ACEA+90]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

Comment: As far as I know, the Qt 5.6 beta is still not released... Did you mean alpha? However, since you are using a "BETA", you shouldn't be suprised if the program crashes. Create a bug report at https://bugreports.qt.io

Comment: I build Qt from commit f128a9a7e1009d9ee11665dce08d5bfafa91ef66; it's latest commit for 5.6 at this moment

Comment: See bug report https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49670

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the crash is not obvious, because [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestjob.html) is not clear on the details how `QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler` should be implemented.

Your program crashes because `QWebEngineUrlRequestJob::reply()` uses the **buffer** parameter later, out of the caller's scope, probably from a different thread. The local variable `QByteArray` **arr** which you declared on the stack (and used as backing storage for the buffer) will be out of scope by then and QWebEngine will be accessing an invalid pointer.

Another thing is, `reply()` does not take ownership of the passed **buffer** object and never deletes it. This introduces a memory leak. You cannot simply delete it right after calling `reply()` for the same reason as above. To ensure the **buffer** object is deleted when no longer needed, connect the **request**'s `destroyed()` signal to the **buffer**'s `deleteLater()` slot.

Here is a complete working and leak-free example:

```
void CustomUrlSchemeHandler::requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *request)
{
    QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer;
    connect(request, SIGNAL(destroyed()), buffer, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    buffer->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    buffer->write("<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>");
    buffer->close();

    request->reply("text/html", buffer);
}
```

Note: You don't need to use a `QByteArray` at all. The default constructor for `QBuffer` allocates its own storage.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the crash is that *arr* goes out of scope.

You have to change

```
QByteArray arr = QString::fromStdString("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>").toUtf8();
QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer(&arr, this);
```

to

```
QByteArray *pArr = new QByteArray(QString::fromStdString("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>").toUtf8());
QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer(pArr, this);
```